# How do I remove quotation mark in columns in KDB

Tags: kdb

I have a table t which contains a column called CMYN. But every cell in that column is enclosed by quotation marks. How can I update that column to get rid of the double quotation marks?

e.g. I want to change the column value from "APPLE" to APPLE

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Cathals answer is likely what you want but just FYI that you can't change it from "APPLE" to APPLE because APPLE isn't a recognised object/datatype by kdb. You can either have a string (aka `"APPLE"`) or a symbol (aka `\`APPLE`). How things are *displayed* in a table is a different matter. Strings are displayed with quotes, symbols are not (and the leading backtick isn't displayed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like casting the column to symbol type is what you're after. See below.

```
q)table:([]sym:5#enlist"APPLE")
q)update`$sym from table
sym
-----
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
APPLE
```